# Ticking sound when stepping on Brake

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, noise

I have this ticking sound somes when I press on the brake while is not moving and on Parking but the Engine is on.I changed the rear rotors, pads , and the right rear right caliper, but the sound is still there.

**What could that be?**

Comment: Two things: 1) What is the vehicle year/make/model? 2) To clarify, *the clicking happens when the vehicle is stopped?* Could you please go back through your question and edit for clarity?

Comment: If you're not moving when the clicking is happening, it's either an electrical relay clicking or something in your ABS.  I would hope it's the $10 relay.  Have a friend step on the pedal while your ear is next to each of your 2 or 3 fuse boxes and try to find the source.  If you still can't find it, put your head next to the ABS module and listen.

Answer (score 1):

If this noise occurs only when the vehicle is in Park, you're probably hearing the park lock getting disengaged. This isn't something to be worried about; perfectly normal.